# How to communicate between code-behind file and ViewModel

Tags: c#, events, mvvm

I am trying to send a message from a code-behind file of a View to a separate ViewModel in order to notify the ViewModel that a collection has changed. I understand the code-behind file usage breaks MVVM principles, but I believe it is justified in this situation.

I have a `WindowsForms` control that I have to use and thus need a `WindowsFormsHost` in my application. The `WindowsFormsHost` sits in the code-behind file, where I'm doing all the groundwork to set up my `WindowsForms` control (which is a video capture control, by the way).

A separate View/ViewModel handles the videos and images captured by this control. At the start of the application, the ViewModel asks the Model to retrieve all of the image/video thumbnails, and then places them in a ListBox in the view for the user to see. Here is where I'm lost.

I need to communicate to the ViewModel that a new image/video has been captured and that the View should be updated. I already have my list of thumbnails set up as an `ObservableCollection` and have set up the `OnPropertyChanged` and the `NotifyCollectionChanged` events.

Those should work, *if* they were being executed. I noticed that they never are, because there is nothing telling them to do so. I tried to set up an `event` that would be raised after a file was successfully saved, but since the file-saving takes part in a different class(a callback class required by the capture control), I need to have an instance of that class in my ViewModel to subscribe to the event.

This means I need to create another instance in my ViewModel, which isn't the instance of the class that is doing the file-saving. Is there an approach I can take that will allow me to communicate between the code-behind file and image/video ViewModel after a UI button is pressed?

Essentially, my desired order of operations is as such:

**1.)** User opens application and sees video stream in one pane and already captured image/videos thumbnails in another (these are stored in two separate folders inside the solution directory for now)

**2.)** User clicks on either "Capture Video" or "Still Image"  button, which will either begin video capture or take an image of the current video frame.

**3.)** If video capture was clicked, user will have to click "Stop" to stop video capture. The video will be saved in the video folder.

**4.)** If "Still Image" was clicked, a frame is captured and stored in an "images" folder. I am creating a `BitmapImage` of the frame after it is captured.

**5.)** The ImageViewModel should be notified that there has been a new image/video saved, and should update the captured images/videos pane.

This sounds to me like the perfect situation for an event, but I can't think of how to properly wire it up without creating extra instances of classes. If some code examples would help, please let me know.

Comment: I was following your question until you started talking about "after a file was successfully saved" -- I don't see how that relates to the earlier description.  Can you list your desired order of operations (preferably using list formatting)?

Comment: Sorry guys, wasn't even paying attention to the formatting. I apologize. I'll make note of that next time. @Justin, yes, I'll edit and do that.

Comment: What?  At first it sounded like your View has a collection that your ViewModel needs to know about.  Then you started talking about saving a file.  Is the View doing that?  It might be easier to understand what you are asking if you post some code.

Comment: @cadrell0 I apologize for the confusion. There is a separate View/ViewModel for already captured images and videos. The control is capturing video and/or images and saving them in a folder in the application directory. The save occurs in a callback function that's required by the capture control. I don't have any control over that. After that save occurs, the View needs to be updated to reflect the new images/videos that had been saved.

Answer (score 0):

You could the [event aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern. There are implementations of this included in MVVM frameworks such as Prism and Caliburn.Micro. Caliburn.Micro includes a NuGet package which just includes the event aggregator, so you don't need to pull down the full framework.

Have a look here - http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator and [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation) for documentation.

In your case the publish of the event can happen in the code behind, and the subscriber would be your view model which responds to the event.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That looks promising. I'll take a look into it and see if it'll solve my issue.